# How can I pass a complex array from the client-side javascript to a server-side node.js function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, canvas

I am very new to Node.js.

I have a canvas object on the webpage that accumulates data in an array as the user clicks on the canvas.  I would like to store this array in a mongodb database via server side javascript.  The only way that I know of to get data from the client environment to the server environtment is via a POST from a form, but the array is currently just a variable in the client side javascript.  Do I have to create html document elements for each item of the array in order to post the data through the request body?  That can't be the only way.  The array is hundreds of elements long.  Please advise!  Thanks so much!

The relevant packages that I am using are: express, ejs, mongodb, and mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to identify the key words that I needed to find what I was looking for.  For others, the package I am using to accomplish this is axios.